# How can I bundle a jQuery HTML application as a Mac OSX app?

Tags: macos, package

I've re-created one of my mother's favorite old games from our C64 days in Javascript and HTML, using jQuery to make it cross-browser.  It's possible she'll want to use it while the network is unavailable, so I've put everything in a single directory.

I'd like to give it to her in a more polished form than a plain URL or a shortcut on her iMac desktop.

I've tried manually creating the app structure, but that requires an executable; making an executable script didn't work.  I've done a Google search, but everybody else wants to create an app for iOS or Android... I just need an app for the Mac OSX desktop and dock.

Am I doomed to providing a URL shortcut?  Ugh.  How do I make a Mac OSX .app out of my HTML and Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with [Cordova OSX](https://github.com/apache/cordova-osx)

It's a phonegap version for mac apps

Comment: it doesn't exist anymore :/

Comment: they've changed the url, fixed now